# ButterKnife @OnClick for views in custom view holder class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view, butterknife

One of my common practice in android **activity/fragment** is to **create custom view holder static class in each fragment/activity that contains only view references.** I bind **fragment/activity** view to this custom view holder as target using ButterKnife. In this case ButterKnife `@OnClick` annotation doesn't work since view references are in view holder class. Please have a look over my code.

Is there any way to overcome this without destroying my view holder class ?

```
public class BookDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_detail_view, container, false);

        // Binding view holder
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(mFragmentView);

        return mFragmentView;
    }

    @OnClick (R.id.book_title)
    public void onBookTitleClicked(TextView v) {
        // This won't work. Is it possible to make it work with view holder class ?
        // If I move this method into ViewHolder class I can't access fragment variables. 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mViewHolder.unbind();
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.book_title) TextView bookTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.book_authors) TextView bookAuthors;

        private Unbinder mButterKnifeUnbinder;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            mButterKnifeUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

        public void unbind() {
            mButterKnifeUnbinder.unbind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try moving this method to your `ViewHolder` class.

Comment: How to access fragment variable easily. Yes. it's possible by passing a reference to ViewHolder class but seeking for more easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do this but here it is:

```
class ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.book_title) TextView bookTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.book_authors) TextView bookAuthors;

    private Unbinder mButterKnifeUnbinder;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        mButterKnifeUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    @OnClick (R.id.book_title)
    public void onBookTitleClicked(TextView v) {
        // this should work
    }

    public void unbind() {
        if(mButterKnifeUnbinder != null) {
            mButterKnifeUnbinder.unbind();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You should NOT call `unbind()` on `onDestroy()` method. For `Fragment`, `unbind()` should be called on `onDestroyView()`.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    if(mViewHolder != null) {
        mViewHolder.unbind();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes unbinding should be inside onDestroyView(). In my original code it was correct. I wrote code snippet seperately that's why I did this mistake. However please look over my comment inside the method.

Comment: You can't access fragment variables because the `ViewHolder` class is static. is there a reason your `ViewHolder` is `static`? If you have class level variables, `ViewHolder` is a sub class and you will be able to access all variables inside the `ViewHolder` if you don't make it static.

Comment: I edited my answer. This way you will be able to access all variables

Comment: Hi th3pat3l, your suggestion is correct. Anyway my preference isn't to access fragment variable from ViewHolder class. I understood now it's a matter of choice cause ButterKnife is unable to serve what I want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of ViewHolder according to my question is just to hold view references, not to access fragment variables. So I guess `onClick` event should be redirected to fragment somehow. This could be done in following way:

```
public class BookDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_detail_view, container, false);

        // Binding view holder
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(this, mFragmentView);

        return mFragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mViewHolder.unbind();
    }

    public void onEditButtonClicked(TextView v) {
        // On click event comes into here
    }

    public void onDeleteButtonClicked(TextView v) {
        // On click event comes into here
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.book_title) TextView bookTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.book_authors) TextView bookAuthors;

        private Unbinder mButterKnifeUnbinder;

        private BookDetailFragment mFragment;

        public ViewHolder(BookDetailFragment fragment, View view) {
            mFragment = fragment;
            mButterKnifeUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

        public void unbind() {
            mButterKnifeUnbinder.unbind();
        }

        @OnClick (R.id.edit_button)
        public void onEditButtonClicked(TextView v) {
            mFragment.onEditButtonClicked(v);
        }

        @OnClick (R.id.delete_button)
        public void onDeleteButtonClicked(TextView v) {
            mFragment.onDeleteButtonClicked(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave your method like this, removing the **public** and the **parameters** (methods OnClick from ButterKnife "does not like" of parameters :) ):

```
@OnClick (R.id.book_title)
void onBookTitleClicked() {
        // This won't work. Is it possible to make it work with view holder class ?
        // If I move this method into ViewHolder class I can't access fragment variables. 
}
```